# struts2: select tag doesn't like beans with "parameters" property?

Tags: properties, struts2, tags, ognl

I have a base class `ReportElement` which has `type` property:

```
public abstract class ReportElement {
    private ReportElementType type;

    public ReportElementType getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(ReportElementType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

`ReportElementType` is just an enum with specified `code` and `i18nKey` properties for each element. I have a couple of subclasses of `ReportElement`, each of them introducing their own properties. One of them is Plot:

```
public class Plot extends ReportElement {
    public Plot() {
        setType(ReportElementType.PLOT);
    }

    private Collection<Parameter> parameters = new ArrayList<Parameter>();

    public Collection<Parameter> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }
}
```

On some page I needed to display a collection of different `ReportElement` instances, so I just used struts2 select tag:

```
<s:select list="myElements" listKey="type.code" listValue="type.i18nKey" size="20"/>
```

This worked like a charm for every element except for `Plot` instaces. Instead of invoking `getType().getCode()` or `getType().getI18nKey()` plain `toString()` was invoked on every instance of `Plot`! After several hours of fun debugging I noticed that during tag evaluation `Plot`'s `getParameters()` method is called! So it seems struts was trying to evaluate `type.code` and `type.i18nKey` using `getParameters()` method! Failing to do that it ignored the existence of the properties, that I have clearly specified for usage!

After renaming `getParameters` to a kind of odd name like `getParamms` the problem gone. Also the problem hasn't occured when using iterator tag together with property tag instead of select tag.

Does anyone have an idea WHY struts select tag uses `parameters` property of my bean, when I have clearly specified what property should be used? Is it some "cool" feature or a bug?

P.S. I use struts 2.2.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument used in all the FreeMarker templates representing a tag's parameters is called `parameters`. By providing a `parameters` property that takes precedence, S2 was unable to get to the object on the stack containing the tag's parameters.

It's neither a cool feature nor a bug, it's just how the templates are implemented. Checking the template source may have saved the few hours of debugging.

Comment: yes, Dave, I have checked this already. So is there any way I can correct this without modifying my bean's method name?

Comment: @pavel_kazlou Off the top of my head, without creating your own theme and renaming everything in the all the templates, I don't have a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found corresponding issue in struts JIRA: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3268

2.3 is specified as fix version.

Comment: FYI, I've closed your duplicate ticket. If you have additional information to add to the [existing ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3268), please do so as a comment.